# Sorting pd fileld in vb file using dfsort in jcl

Tags: file, sorting, mainframe, jcl, packed-decimal

I have a vb file length of 2504. I need to sort the field (234,7)
Field declaration- S9(13) comp-3.
Since it is a vb file I did like below.

```
  //Sysin dd*
     Sort fields= (238,7,pd,A)
  /*
```

But it's not sorting properly .
Pls help ..
Thank you!!

Comment: The first **4 bytes** in a record in a **VB** file are the RDW (basically record Length). You need to add 4 bytes to starting positions when sorting. If you did not allow for the 4 bytes try `Sort fields=(2427,pd,A)`

Comment: Thanks Bruce..my field real length is 234..Have already added 4 and tried

Comment: from memory it is position followed by length

Comment: I assume there are some typos in your sort statement, because DFSORT would not accept neither the space after `fields=`, nor would it accept lower case. If DFSORT did not complain, `FIELDS=(238,7,PD,A)` would definitely sort a packed decimal field. Would you please show at least one input record's data in hexdecimal notation?

Comment: Please remoce the `JCL`tag. This has nothing to do with `JCL` whatsoever.